# Update Listview row UI from custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

I am working on to update image of one button in a row inside custom listview. I have created a custom adapter class for the listview. On click of the button inside one row of listview I have open a custom dialog. Onclick of the **OK button** of dialog now I want t change the image of the button inside that listview.

Currently I have just made the static button inside the listview and passed the object of that button to the custom dialog method. I am using the simple listview not the fragments.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ItemInfoViewHolder viewHolder;
        Log.d("Inside Get View", ""+position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = listInflater.inflate(R.layout.iteminfo_view_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ItemInfoViewHolder();
            viewHolder.itemSelection = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemselectionTextview);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ItemInfoViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        try{
            viewHolder.itemSelection.setId(itemsInfo.get(position).getId());
            );

            viewHolder.itemSelection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("Item Id"+v.getId());
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int itemId = v.getId();
                    SelectPopup selectPopup = new SelectPopup(mContext, R.style.myCoolDialog);
                    selectPopup.selectQuantity(itemsInfo,itemId,viewHolder.itemSelection);
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Here **viewHolder.itemSelection** is the object of that button which I am passing to the custom dialog method. By this the image is update randomly on the listview on any row.

Please suggest me some better idea to do that.

Comment: Can you post your complete getView-method? The problem is that you should alter your datamodel behind your Adapter and let the ListView update itself based on that in stead of changing the views directly yourself.

Comment: @DroidBender I have paste whole getview code. Also I have create cutom Dialog in other class SelectPopup and calling method of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief explanation:

An `Adapter` acts as a controller of your datamodel, in your case a `List<itemsInfo>`, and updates its assigned `ListView` accordingly inside the getView()-method.

Your goal is to change the visual state of the `ListView` whenever you do a certain action, a click. This is simply done by changing the datamodel behind the `Adapter` of your `ListView` whenever you perform your action and ask your `ListView` to redraw itself with help of the `Adapter`.

In code:

1. Add a field to your itemsInfo that will hold a certain state. This can be in any format or form but for now, let's use a boolean called isPressed.
2. In your getView(), your `View` will initialize itself depending on this pressed state.

   ```
   viewHolder.itemSelection.whatevermethodyouwant(itemsInfo.get(position).isPressed)
   ```
3. When you want to change the state of your row, simply change the datamodel at the given position and update the `ListView` again.

   ```
   viewHolder.itemSelection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           itemsInfo.get(position).setPressed(whatever);
           notifyDataSetChanged(); // This is a call for your Adapter and will refill the ListView
       }
   });
   ```

This is just pseudo code to explain the flow of events. Hope it will help you to improve your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have to open up a Custom dialog first onClick of the ListItem and then change the state of the row onClick of the OK of that dialog which I have made in other class.

Comment: Then you can simply create a callback that goes back to your Adapter when your press the OK and edit/update your itemsInfo model accordingly. To create interfaces or callback, you can see an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22326209/1479570