# return arraylist from Asynctask

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am trying to populate a listview using an ArrayList which has to be returned from Asynctask according to what is told here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22326209/8520030. I am trying to display zip files as listview.I am using asynctask as normally it takes too much time to load items in the listview. **But nothing gets displayed in listview on using Asynctask. Like it doesn't get populated with listview items.**  I have done this till now.

```
public interface IAsyncTask {

    ArrayList<String> IAmFinished(ArrayList<File> arrayList);
}

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements IAsyncTask {

public static ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
Longoperation longoperation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    File dir1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    longoperation = new Longoperation(dir1, this);
    longoperation.execute();
    JazzyListView lv = (JazzyListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name));
}

@Override
public ArrayList<String> IAmFinished(ArrayList<File> list) {
    for(int i=0;i< list.size();i++){
        name.add(list.get(i).getName());
    }
    return name;
}

private class Long operation extends AsyncTask<File, Void, ArrayList<File>>{

    File dir;
    private static final String TAG = "com.example.dell_1.myapp3.Zip";
    private IAsyncTask asyncTaskListener;

    public Longoperation(File dir,IAsyncTask asyncTaskListener) {
        this.dir = dir;
        this.asyncTaskListener = asyncTaskListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<File> doInBackground(File... params) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    doInBackground(listFile[i]);

                } else {

                    boolean booleanpdf = false;
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".zip") || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jar")) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < fileList.size(); j++) {
                            if (fileList.get(j).getName().equals(listFile[i].getName())) {
                                booleanpdf = true;
                            } else {

                            }
                        }

                        if (booleanpdf) {
                            booleanpdf = false;
                        } else {
                            fileList.add(listFile[i]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<File> list) {
        asyncTaskListener.IAmFinished(list);
    }
}
}
```

But I am not able to populate the listview. **Nothing gets displayed in the listview .**
How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn’t your asyncTask1 null? You should get an NPE then.

Comment: Try setting the adapter of your listview in the IAmFinished method. You are setting the adapter to an empty list.

Comment: How is it null when I am passing an arraylist in `onPostExecute()` ? I am not getting an NPE @algrid

Answer (score 0):

Remove following line from onCreate.

```
IAmFinished(fileList);
```

Cut following lines from onCreate and paste in IamFinished after for loop.

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name));
```

And do not forgot to declair JazzyListView globaly.

End of the modifing your code looks like.

```
    public interface IAsyncTask {

    ArrayList<String> IAmFinished(ArrayList<File> arrayList);
}

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements IAsyncTask {


public static ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
Longoperation longoperation;
JazzyListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    File dir1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    longoperation = new Longoperation(dir1, this);
    longoperation.execute();
    lv = (JazzyListView) findViewById(R.id.list);



}

@Override
public ArrayList<String> IAmFinished(ArrayList<File> list) {
    for(int i=0;i< list.size();i++){
        name.add(list.get(i).getName());
    }

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name));
    return name;
}

private class Longoperation extends AsyncTask<File, Void, ArrayList<File>>{

    File dir;
    private static final String TAG = "com.example.dell_1.myapp3.Zip";
    private IAsyncTask asyncTaskListener;

    public Longoperation(File dir,IAsyncTask asyncTaskListener) {
        this.dir = dir;
        this.asyncTaskListener = asyncTaskListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<File> doInBackground(File... params) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    doInBackground(listFile[i]);

                } else {

                    boolean booleanpdf = false;
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".zip") || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jar")) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < fileList.size(); j++) {
                            if (fileList.get(j).getName().equals(listFile[i].getName())) {
                                booleanpdf = true;
                            } else {

                            }
                        }

                        if (booleanpdf) {
                            booleanpdf = false;
                        } else {
                            fileList.add(listFile[i]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<File> list) {
        asyncTaskListener.IAmFinished(list);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: the end result is still the same @Samarth

Comment: Can your code receive ArrayList<File> list in IamFinished? Check by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the adapter by calling [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()). Something like this:

```
lv = (JazzyListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
..
lv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or you can use something like this:

```
// need to make the class scope variable.
ArrayAdapter mAdapter;

// create the adapter
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name)
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

...
// refresh the adapter in your listener.
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: its not working and I think the main problem is that I am not able to return arraylist from `doInBackground()` method in Asynctask